# Can you use the Elemental metamagic to then use Flaring metamagic?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic, metamagic

Can I use the [Elemental Spell](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/metamagic-feats/elemental-spell-metamagic) metamagic to change, say Cone of Cold, to deal fire damage, then use [Flaring Spell](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/metamagic-feats/flaring-spell-metamagic) metamagic to cause it to dazzle?

The feat says:

> "A flare spell causes a creature that takes fire or electricity damage from the affected spell to become dazzled"

Leading me to think I can.

Comment: Not only *can't* you, you really *shouldn't*. You just wasted a 7th or 8th level spell slot to...impose a -1 penalty to attack rolls and perception checks?

Comment: Its really more the theory of the thing. If it would work for Cone of Cold, it would also work for some random 2nd level spell, as well as other metamagic feats, which would be worth pursuing.

Comment: I see where you're going with this—this is how we got the Locate City Bomb in 3.5—but you really don't want to pursue dazzling as a condition, ever. A zero level spell (flare) lets you Dazzle someone for a minute—clearly it isn't ever worth a +1 level adjustment

Comment: You would be better off asking about what you're trying to accomplish than asking about specific instances.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, I don't think that you can.

> You can manipulate the elemental nature of your spells.
>
> Benefit: Choose one energy type: acid, cold, electricity, or fire. You may replace a spell’s normal damage with that energy type or split the spell’s damage, so that half is of that energy type and half is of its normal type.

Note, it doesn't say that the base spell changes, only the damage type that is inflicted. So, you are still casting Cone of Cold, but the damage type is fire instead of cold. The key part of the Flaring that you left out is:

> You dazzle creatures when you affect them with a spell that has the fire, light, or electricity descriptor.

So, since the original spell descriptor does not have the fire, light or electricity descriptor, the Flaring feat will not work.

This is, however, open to other interpretations on the part of your GM.